# Csv list of country codes/names?

Tags: country-codes

Where can I get a list of easily parseable country codes and names? Note: 2 letter codes wanted. Examples:

au,Australia

uk,United Kingdom

us,United States

etc

Answer (score 93, accepted):

[The ISO 3166-1 list of country codes](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes.htm) is what I was looking for.

For more information you can also find [general information about country codes on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code) and [a - possibly more up to date list - ISO 3166-1 list as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1#Current_codes).

Edit: Posting it here:

```
Country Name;ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 code

AFGHANISTAN;AF
ÅLAND ISLANDS;AX
ALBANIA;AL
ALGERIA;DZ
AMERICAN SAMOA;AS
ANDORRA;AD
ANGOLA;AO
ANGUILLA;AI
ANTARCTICA;AQ
ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA;AG
ARGENTINA;AR
ARMENIA;AM
ARUBA;AW
AUSTRALIA;AU
AUSTRIA;AT
AZERBAIJAN;AZ
BAHAMAS;BS
BAHRAIN;BH
BANGLADESH;BD
BARBADOS;BB
BELARUS;BY
BELGIUM;BE
BELIZE;BZ
BENIN;BJ
BERMUDA;BM
BHUTAN;BT
BOLIVIA, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF;BO
BONAIRE, SINT EUSTATIUS AND SABA;BQ
BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA;BA
BOTSWANA;BW
BOUVET ISLAND;BV
BRAZIL;BR
BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY;IO
BRUNEI DARUSSALAM;BN
BULGARIA;BG
BURKINA FASO;BF
BURUNDI;BI
CAMBODIA;KH
CAMEROON;CM
CANADA;CA
CAPE VERDE;CV
CAYMAN ISLANDS;KY
CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC;CF
CHAD;TD
CHILE;CL
CHINA;CN
CHRISTMAS ISLAND;CX
COCOS (KEELING) ISLANDS;CC
COLOMBIA;CO
COMOROS;KM
CONGO;CG
CONGO, THE DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE;CD
COOK ISLANDS;CK
COSTA RICA;CR
CÔTE D'IVOIRE;CI
CROATIA;HR
CUBA;CU
CURAÇAO;CW
CYPRUS;CY
CZECH REPUBLIC;CZ
DENMARK;DK
DJIBOUTI;DJ
DOMINICA;DM
DOMINICAN REPUBLIC;DO
ECUADOR;EC
EGYPT;EG
EL SALVADOR;SV
EQUATORIAL GUINEA;GQ
ERITREA;ER
ESTONIA;EE
ETHIOPIA;ET
FALKLAND ISLANDS (MALVINAS);FK
FAROE ISLANDS;FO
FIJI;FJ
FINLAND;FI
FRANCE;FR
FRENCH GUIANA;GF
FRENCH POLYNESIA;PF
FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES;TF
GABON;GA
GAMBIA;GM
GEORGIA;GE
GERMANY;DE
GHANA;GH
GIBRALTAR;GI
GREECE;GR
GREENLAND;GL
GRENADA;GD
GUADELOUPE;GP
GUAM;GU
GUATEMALA;GT
GUERNSEY;GG
GUINEA;GN
GUINEA-BISSAU;GW
GUYANA;GY
HAITI;HT
HEARD ISLAND AND MCDONALD ISLANDS;HM
HOLY SEE (VATICAN CITY STATE);VA
HONDURAS;HN
HONG KONG;HK
HUNGARY;HU
ICELAND;IS
INDIA;IN
INDONESIA;ID
IRAN, ISLAMIC REPUBLIC OF;IR
IRAQ;IQ
IRELAND;IE
ISLE OF MAN;IM
ISRAEL;IL
ITALY;IT
JAMAICA;JM
JAPAN;JP
JERSEY;JE
JORDAN;JO
KAZAKHSTAN;KZ
KENYA;KE
KIRIBATI;KI
KOREA, DEMOCRATIC PEOPLE'S REPUBLIC OF;KP
KOREA, REPUBLIC OF;KR
KUWAIT;KW
KYRGYZSTAN;KG
LAO PEOPLE'S DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC;LA
LATVIA;LV
LEBANON;LB
LESOTHO;LS
LIBERIA;LR
LIBYA;LY
LIECHTENSTEIN;LI
LITHUANIA;LT
LUXEMBOURG;LU
MACAO;MO
MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF;MK
MADAGASCAR;MG
MALAWI;MW
MALAYSIA;MY
MALDIVES;MV
MALI;ML
MALTA;MT
MARSHALL ISLANDS;MH
MARTINIQUE;MQ
MAURITANIA;MR
MAURITIUS;MU
MAYOTTE;YT
MEXICO;MX
MICRONESIA, FEDERATED STATES OF;FM
MOLDOVA, REPUBLIC OF;MD
MONACO;MC
MONGOLIA;MN
MONTENEGRO;ME
MONTSERRAT;MS
MOROCCO;MA
MOZAMBIQUE;MZ
MYANMAR;MM
NAMIBIA;NA
NAURU;NR
NEPAL;NP
NETHERLANDS;NL
NEW CALEDONIA;NC
NEW ZEALAND;NZ
NICARAGUA;NI
NIGER;NE
NIGERIA;NG
NIUE;NU
NORFOLK ISLAND;NF
NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS;MP
NORWAY;NO
OMAN;OM
PAKISTAN;PK
PALAU;PW
PALESTINE, STATE OF;PS
PANAMA;PA
PAPUA NEW GUINEA;PG
PARAGUAY;PY
PERU;PE
PHILIPPINES;PH
PITCAIRN;PN
POLAND;PL
PORTUGAL;PT
PUERTO RICO;PR
QATAR;QA
RÉUNION;RE
ROMANIA;RO
RUSSIAN FEDERATION;RU
RWANDA;RW
SAINT BARTHÉLEMY;BL
SAINT HELENA, ASCENSION AND TRISTAN DA CUNHA;SH
SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS;KN
SAINT LUCIA;LC
SAINT MARTIN (FRENCH PART);MF
SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON;PM
SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES;VC
SAMOA;WS
SAN MARINO;SM
SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE;ST
SAUDI ARABIA;SA
SENEGAL;SN
SERBIA;RS
SEYCHELLES;SC
SIERRA LEONE;SL
SINGAPORE;SG
SINT MAARTEN (DUTCH PART);SX
SLOVAKIA;SK
SLOVENIA;SI
SOLOMON ISLANDS;SB
SOMALIA;SO
SOUTH AFRICA;ZA
SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS;GS
SOUTH SUDAN;SS
SPAIN;ES
SRI LANKA;LK
SUDAN;SD
SURINAME;SR
SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN;SJ
SWAZILAND;SZ
SWEDEN;SE
SWITZERLAND;CH
SYRIAN ARAB REPUBLIC;SY
TAIWAN, PROVINCE OF CHINA;TW
TAJIKISTAN;TJ
TANZANIA, UNITED REPUBLIC OF;TZ
THAILAND;TH
TIMOR-LESTE;TL
TOGO;TG
TOKELAU;TK
TONGA;TO
TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO;TT
TUNISIA;TN
TURKEY;TR
TURKMENISTAN;TM
TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS;TC
TUVALU;TV
UGANDA;UG
UKRAINE;UA
UNITED ARAB EMIRATES;AE
UNITED KINGDOM;GB
UNITED STATES;US
UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS;UM
URUGUAY;UY
UZBEKISTAN;UZ
VANUATU;VU
VENEZUELA, BOLIVARIAN REPUBLIC OF;VE
VIETNAM;VN
VIRGIN ISLANDS, BRITISH;VG
VIRGIN ISLANDS, U.S.;VI
WALLIS AND FUTUNA;WF
WESTERN SAHARA;EH
YEMEN;YE
ZAMBIA;ZM
ZIMBABWE;ZW
```

Comment: GitHub repo with humanized country names in multiple languages in multiple formats: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/blob/master/country/cldr/en/country.csv (see my answer below)

Comment: .... and indeed the link died! ha ha, thanks for the post!

Comment: Be warned that countries only seem static because we humans live so shortly, the number and name of countries varies all the time. This answer and your script may live on after your life but certainly that of countries as well.

Answer (score 46):

Here's a maintained repo of country codes with friendly country names in multiple languages and in many formats, including text, CSV, JSON, YAML, XML, SQL, and others:

https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list

The English CSV dump from the above repo: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/blob/master/data/en_US/country.csv

Comment: Seems not to be so maintained anymore...

Comment: @DioF The owner responded to a pull request mid Feb. 2017. He might not have committed for a while, but I would hardly call this repo "not so maintained".

Answer (score 12):

In case it can help anyone, I just took the list of ISO 3166 country codes and names in English and French and put them together in CSV and SQL format: http://blog.plsoucy.com/2012/04/iso-3166-country-code-list-csv-sql/

While doing that, I fixed the capitalization so names aren't all uppercase, and renamed a few countries to the name that is used on Wikipedia, so "MACEDONIA, THE FORMER YUGOSLAV REPUBLIC OF" became "Macedonia" for example. That should allow for shorter lists.

Feel free to use these if you want.

Comment: There's a GitHub repo with humanized country names in multiple languages in multiple formats: https://github.com/umpirsky/country-list/blob/master/country/cldr/en/country.csv (see my answer below)

Comment: If you just want the English ISO dump along with table definitions, I maintain this here: http://kejser.org/resources/free-data/free-data-countries-world/

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at ISO  http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes/country_names_and_code_elements.htm  It is not CSV but you can easily copy and paste it into a file, or you can buy the file from ISO

updated the link